# Prevent React from displaying props meant for Styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I use `Styled-Components` with `React`.

My code looks like this:

```
const StyledLink = styled.a<StyledProps>`
  font-size: ${(props) => pxToRem(props.fontSize!)};

  //disabled state
  ${(props) =>
    props.disabled &&
    css`
      color: grey;
      pointer-events: none;
    `}
`
const Link = ({href, disabled, fontSize = 16, children}: Props) => {
  return(
    <StyledLink href={href} fontSize={fontSize} disabled={disabled}>{children}</StyledLink>
  )
}
```

Everything works fine, however when I inspect my elements I see:

```
<a href="#" font-size="16" disabled>Some Link</a>
```

I want `fontSize` and `disabled` to be props that target only `Styled-Components`. I don't want them to applied for `React` element.
Is there a better way of doing that without changing props names to something like `styledFontSize` and `styledDisabled`?

Comment: you should be looking for transient props: https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props where dollar sign prefix avoid the property passing down to DOM

Comment: Mic Fung, this is a good answer. If you could leave it below, I can mark it as right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

styled-components provides `transient props` for those who wants to avoid property passing down to DOM or React node where the property name should have `$` (dollar sign) prefix.

**Using `$` transient props**:

```js
const StyledLink = styled.a<StyledProps>`
  font-size: ${(props) => pxToRem(props.$fontSize!)};

  //disabled state
  ${(props) =>
    props.$disabled &&
    css`
      color: grey;
      pointer-events: none;
    `}
`

const Link = ({href, disabled, fontSize = 16, children}: Props) => {
  return(
    <StyledLink href={href} $fontSize={fontSize} $disabled={disabled}>{children}</StyledLink>
  )
}
```